# Category recursion in Django

Tags: python, django, recursion

Ok I have been searching everywhere for this and can't seem to find anyway to do it elegantly. Basically I have a Category model that has a category field that a book belongs to and then a parent for the category.

I am trying to create a template to display:

Parent1

- Category1
- -- booka
- -- bookb
- Category2
- --bookb
- --bookc

Parent2

- Category3
- -- bookb
- -- bookd

My models are:

```
class Category(models.Model):
        category = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        parent = TreeForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='children')
class Book(models.Model):
        bookname=models.CharField(_('bookname'), max_length=255)
        author=models.CharField(_('author'), max_length=255)
        manufacturer=models.CharField(_('manufacturer'), max_length=255)
        description=models.TextField(_('description'), blank=True)
        coverart = models.ImageField(upload_to="coverart", blank=True, null=True)
        adder=models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="added_models", verbose_name=_('adder'))
        added=models.DateTimeField(_('added'), default=datetime.now)
        category=models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='cat')
        content=models.TextField(blank=True)
```

Any ideas on the best way to do this in my views/template? It's just a basic database browsing structure, but the reverse looking up of the categories/books that belong to a parent is confusing me.

Answer (score 2):

```
<ul>
{% for parent in categories %}
    <li>{{ parent.category }}
        <ul>
        {% for category in parent.children.all %}
        <li>{{ category.category }}
            <ul>
            {% for book in category.book_set.all %}
                <li>{{ book.bookname }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, I am trying this code but it tells me Caught TypeError while rendering: 'RelatedManager' object is not iterable for the line {% for parent in categories %}.. Any ideas? I have passed the categories as 
categories = Category.objects.all() from my view.py.

Comment: @Natasha ah sorry, there was a missing `all` in the line `for category in parent.children.all`. Corrected.

Comment: Thanks Daniel! Worked like a charm. Introduced a couple things I didn't know existed.

Answer (score 2):

try to use the [django mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/) he help you to create a tree struct on database. Very useful

he have some template tags to help to create the html

Comment: Thanks, I'll go through a tutorial on that this afternoon and let you know how it goes.